# Preventing Duplicate URLs in MongoDB Database with URL Standardization

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on a URL shortening application in Node.js using Express and MongoDB. In my application, I am trying to standardize the URLs before storing them in my MongoDB database by adding 'https://' to the beginning of the URLs that don't already have it.

However, I'm running into an issue where if I submit "www.google.com", it gets stored in the database, and then if I submit "https://www.google.com/" later, it also gets stored in the database as a separate document, even though I consider them to be the same URL.

```
app.post('/api/shorturl', (request, response) => {
  let inputUrl = request.body['url'];
 
  if (!inputUrl.startsWith('https://') && !inputUrl.startsWith('http://')) {
    inputUrl = "https://" + inputUrl;
  }
  const dnsLookUp = dns.lookup(urlparser.parse(inputUrl).hostname, (error, address) => {
    if (!address) {
      return response.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
    } else {
      Url.findOne({ original: inputUrl }, (error, existingUrl) => {
        if (!error && existingUrl) {
          responseObject['original_url'] = existingUrl.original;
          responseObject['short_url'] = existingUrl.short;
          return response.json(responseObject);
        } else {
          let inputShort = 1;

          Url.findOne({})
            .sort({ short: 'desc' })
            .exec((error, result) => {
              if (!error && result != undefined) {
                inputShort = result.short + 1;
              }

              Url.create({ original: inputUrl, short: inputShort }, (error, savedUrl) => {
                if (!error) {
                  responseObject['original_url'] = savedUrl.original;
                  responseObject['short_url'] = savedUrl.short;
                  response.json(responseObject);
                }
              });
            });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, I'm using Url.findOne({ original: inputUrl }) to check for duplicates before storing a new URL. However, this isn't working as I expected. It seems to treat "www.google.com" and "https://www.google.com/" as different URLs and allows them to be stored as separate documents.

What should I modify in my code to prevent these kinds of duplicates from being stored in the database? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!